# How to mix csrf enabled and disabled spring websockets in one application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-websocket

I have an application where I need two different websocket setups:

1. one for allowing communication between the application and remote Java-based clients

   - uses stateless comms (auth token is included in each request, also in the websocket connect request)
   - csrf needs to be disabled
2. one for allowing async push notifications from the application to its own web UI.

   - uses normal session authentication
   - csrf needs to be, or should preferably be, enabled (correct me if I'm wrong?)

Now, in Spring, to disable cross origin checking for websockets one needs to extend `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` e.g. as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(final MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages.anyMessage().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The question is, how can I have it disabled for some websockets and enabled for others?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the method `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer#configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration)`, when you have the `sameOriginDisabled` set to `false`, it simply register a `CsrfChannelInterceptor`:

```java
if (!sameOriginDisabled()) {
    registration.setInterceptors(this.context.getBean(CsrfChannelInterceptor.class));
}
```

And after that, it calls the `customizeClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration)` method.

I can't test now, but I think you can override the method `customizeClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration)` and do the following:

```java
@Override
protected void customizeClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
     registration.addInterceptor(myCustomCsrfChannelInterceptor());
}

private CsrfChannelInterceptor myCustomCsrfChannelInterceptor() {
    return new MyCustomCsrfChannelInterceptor();
}

private static class MyCustomCsrfChannelInterceptor {
    private MessageMatcher<Object> matcher = //create your MessageMatcher with your rules

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        if (!this.matcher.matches(message)) {
            return message;
        }
        //copy the content from `CsrfChannelInterceptor`
    }
}
```

In summary, what you are doing is creating a custom `CsrfChannelInterceptor` that will use a custom `MessageMatcher` with your own rules to check if it should apply to that `Message`, and the rest is just a copy of the original interceptor.

Comment: Ah, this is very helpful, I will explore this a bit further! Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure this will work. The customizeClientInboundChannel function is called after the adding of the CsrfChannelInterceptor if sameOriginDisabled returns false. However, if sameOriginDisabled returns true, there is a whole bunch of code in afterSingletonsInstantiated which does not get executed. That last function does certain initialization tasks depending on whether same origin is enabled or not which cannot be set on the fly based on the actual message.